# Difficulty understanding statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having a very difficult time even grasping the simple concept behind how to tackle some of these problems.

> In 2012, about 24% of high school seniors reported binge drinking
>   (defined as 5 or more drinks in a row in the past two weeks), a
>   substantial drop since the late 1990s. A simple random sample of 500
>   high school seniors is to be taken.
>
> a) Define the population and the sample c) What is the approximate
>   distribution of all sample proportions?

Would the overall population be ALL high school seniors and the sample would be the randomly 500 selected high school seniors?

For c: I don't quite understand what it's even asking. How do I compute the distribution of a data set I do not have?

Comment: Hint: There are two possible outcomes for "do you binge drink". What type of distribution is this? Next, the probability for a yes- what does this tell you about the parameter of this distribution?

Comment: The type of distribution would binomial since we are limited to purely yes or no answers. Would we base our distribution on comparing the original percent of high school seniors who binge drink against our sample size?

i.e.

squareRoot( (.25 (1-.25) / 500) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how your random variables look like if you want to model the answers of one person or 500 people.

Regarding c): Be $X_i$ iid then how is $$\sum^{500}_{i=1}X_i$$ approximately distributed? You might want to center and normalize it.

Comment: I don't quite understand the notation, my apologies as I'm sure with further understanding that your solution is extremely helpful.

Comment: @illusionist hm, are you in school or studying? you know what random variables are? Do you know the Central limit theorem? $X_i$ are random variables which are iid (identically independent distributed).
Centering a random variable is subtracting the expected value from it. $\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}(X)]=0$. So $(X-\mathbb{E}[X])$ is a centered random variable. Normalizing is dividing through the standard deviation (the sqrt of the variance) with the resulting random variable having variance=1